# Is custom domain SSL binding necessary when app service is inside an App Service Environment

Tags: azure, ssl, app-service-environment

When having an App Service (in Azure) inside an App Service Environment, and the App Service is using an Custom Domain. Is there any need to add an SSL certificate to the App Service, since the ILB in App Service Environment already have a SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [ILB ASE certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/certificates#ilb-ase-certificates) document,

> There are two options for configuring certificates with your ILB ASE.
>   You can set a **wildcard default certificate** for the ILB ASE or
>   **set certificates on the individual web apps in the ASE.**

I think if you have a wildcard default certificate for the ILB ASE, or you have SSL cert for your specific web app, you do not need to add an invidividual SSL certificate for that specific web app, otherwise, you will need to upload an SSL cert for each web app service in ASE.

Comment: Strange how the input from others can make that what one reads becomes so much easier to understand. I  have read the same document that you refer to earlier, but after your input, everything became clear. Thanks!